# Opening excel file working fine, but if I schedule the script through Windows Task Scheduler, it's not working

Tags: excel, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I am experiencing an issue with my VBScript.

I have below code working fine when I run it directly (by double clicking on it, it's triggering `wscript`). I have some 1000 .xls files in `FilePath`.

```
FilePath = "c:\test"

Set SourceFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FilePath+"\")

For Each file In SourceFolder.Files
    If Right(LCase(file.Name), 4)=".xls" Then
        OutFile = OutFilePath + "\" + Left(file.Name, Len(file.Name)-4) + ".csv"
        Set ExcelObject = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(file.Path)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then objLogFile.WriteLine "Exception occured(1): " + Err.Decscription

        RowCount = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        ColumnCount = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count

        For i=1 To RowCount
            For j=1 To ColumnCount
                inText = ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(i,j).Value
                inText = Replace(inText, vbCr, " ")
                inText = Replace(inText, vbLf, " ")
                inText = Replace(inText, ",", " ")
                ExcelObject.Sheets(1).Cells(i,j).Value = inText
            Next
        Next
        ExcelObject.SaveAs OutFile, 6
        ExcelObject.Close False
    End If
Next
```

If I schedule the same script in the Windows Task Scheduler, it is not throwing any error also, its just running (I can see `wscript` running in the Task Manager).

I tried to capture what error it is throwing, but I couldn't capture. 
After writing some log next to every line, I got to know that it is giving error in the below line.

```
Set ExcelObject = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(file.path)
```

I tried to capture error by putting the statements `On Error Resume Next` and below `If` condition (handled all the `ObjLogFile` object related code)

```
If Err.Number <> 0 Then objLogFile.WriteLine "Exception occured(1): " + Err.Decscription
```

Still it is not capturing the error.

Please help me, how to proceed with the error with the following line. Though it is working fine when I run directly, it's not working when I schedule.

```
Set ExcelObject = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(file.path)
```

Comment: Off hand my guess would be that it is trying to open a window (for excel) but it is not allowed to because it's a scheduled task.

Comment: You might find this answer helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194129/vbscript-to-open-an-excel-file-in-windows-10-via-task-scheduler?rq=1

Comment: Thank you RBarryYoung, I tried with Cscript also, It didn't work. If I see the process in Task Manager, it is running with my user ID, but not showing until I select show process for all users. May be it is running with another user?? there Excel not installed??, how to include, excel run time libraries to my script?

Comment: Show your scheduled task settings. Also, your code doesn't show how you instantiate `oExcel`. Did you set `oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False`?

Comment: Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
I have used this to instantiate OExcel

Comment: Yes, it's probably running under another username.  You can add columns to Task Manager to see which.  Not sure, but you should be able to tell The Scheduler what account to run under.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am using Excel Objects, which are interactive, I cann't give the option in the scheduler "Run whether user is logged on or not"

I changed this option to "Run only when user is logged on"

Its working now. Thank you all for your suggestions.